# How to set a parameter based on the selection of a previous parameter in a parameterized build?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've configured a Jenkins job that creates a CloudFormation stack which contains among other things creation of a RDS DB instance and restores the DB instance from the latest available snapshot for that database in a specific environment.

There are 3 different environments; *Dev*, *Stg* and *Prd* and each environment has its own database.

Currently, when a user chooses to *Build with parameters*, he's asked to choose among other stuff, `Environment` from a *Choice Parameter* list and a RDS snapshot ID from an *Extended Parameter* list which is populated (by running some Groovy code) with the latest RDS snapshot IDs of each one of the databases (*Dev*, *Stg*, *Prd*).

So basically, the user needs to manually select `Environment` name and RDS snapshot ID.

In order to avoid human errors such as choosing *Prd* as `Environment` and *Dev* for *RDS Snapshot ID*, I'd like to configure the `RDSSnapshotId` parameter (the one which is populated by a Groovy script) to be set conditionally by the `Environment` selected.

Meaning that if the user selects *Dev* the `RDSSnapshotId` parameter will be populated with the corresponding RDS Snapshot IDs per that Environment.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new project that runs a Groovy script which creates a file in your CloudFormation job's folder according to 4. below and then runs your CloudFormation job.
2. Select ***Extended Choice Parameter*** → ◉ *Multi-level Parameter Types*
3. Select *Parameter Type*: *Multi-Level Single-Select* <kbd>▼</kbd>
4. *Property File*: `<CloudFormation job's folder>/ChoiceParameters.txt`

   Looks like:

   ```
   Environment→RDS Snapshot ID
   Dev→Dev ID 1
   Dev→Dev ID 2
   Stg→Stg ID 1
   Stg→Stg ID 2
   Prd→Prd ID 1
   Prd→Prd ID 2
   ```
5. *Value*: `Environment,RDS Snapshot ID`

That's the theory, at least. Unfortunately it doesn't work in my Jenkins v2.73.3 with
Extended Choice Parameter Plug-In v0.76 atm (no second level items are displayed after selecting a first level item), but I know that it worked with previous versions.

Got it: The parameter's *Name* must not contain spaces, of course, since it becomes an environment variable.

**UPDATE**

I tried the example mentioned at [*Extended Choice Parameter plugin*](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) → *Version 0.44 (Jun 02, 2015)* → *Advanced Ex:* and it looks promising at first sight.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using upstream/downstream jobs if it's possible to do with one job.

Comment: @ItaiGanot There are no _Pre-Parameter-Selection Actions_ available in a Jenkins project (yet? I had various situations where this would have come in handy, like yours). Maybe the example mentioned at [_Extended Choice Parameter plugin_](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) → _Version 0.44 (Jun 02, 2015)_ → _Advanced Ex:_ can achieve this, but I 've never tried that. If you're going to try that please provide a response here whether it worked or not. I'm really interested to know.